# Assembly - how to set frequency of interrupt

Tags: assembly, avr

Using assembly and AVR Microcontroller I want to write program which causes the interrupt handling with a certain frequency, eg 10 Hz.
first I set the stack and the timer:

```
.cseg

.org jmp restart;

.org 0x002E tjmp timer_fun


restart:
cli
ldi R16, HIGH(RAMEND)
out SPH, R16
ldi R16, LOW(RAMEND)
out SPL, R16
sei

ldi R17, 1<<CSOO
out TCCR0, R17
ldi R16, 1<<TOIE0
out TIMSK, R16
```

But now, I don't know how to set this frequency?

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff - yup - first, read user manual for chip, then hardware spec for xtal freq, then work it out.  I'm guessing 8-bit controller from the code.

Comment: @MartinJames - Different AVR MCUs have different meaning of timer-related registers.  Even register names may vary: `TCCR0` vs `TCCR0A,TCCR0B`.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by counting the number of interrupts triggered. It would depend on the input frequency for the timer (which I guess would typically be the same as the CPU frequency).

Let's say that the input frequency is 16000000 Hz:

Starting at a count of 0 (`TCNT0` set to 0), and a prescaler of 256 (`TCCR0` set to `1<<CS02`) would cause a timer overflow at 16000000/256 == 62500 Hz.

Your timer interrupt service routine could then do something like this (I'm using C here, but you get the idea):

```
counter++;
if (counter == 6250) {
    // We should end up in here approximately 10 times/second
    counter = 0;
}
```