# Toggle leds with interrupts ATMEGA32A

Tags: assembly, interrupt, avr

I have a school task but even the teacher don't know how to do it...
We have to create a program that let the leds blink with a frequency of 1Hz. The chip we use is a ATmega32A at 3,6864 MHz.
The program must contain interrupts so the main program can go to sleep.

now my question i have found SEI and the RETI functions but do i understand it correctly that i have to write 2 assembly programs?

1 with the main loop to control the leds.

1 that generates the 2Hz interrupt to toggle the leds?

tnx in advance

Comment: See also [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16730519/assembly-how-to-set-frequency-of-interrupt)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have got the code working the following code is for a ATmega32A with a clock of 3686400Hz crystal

```
.org 0x000
    rjmp    reset
.org 0x00E
    rjmp    tc0_ocm_isr

.equ    dirleds     =DDRB
.equ    leds        =PORTB
.equ    allout      =0b1111_1111
.equ    allin       =0b0000_0000

.def    temp = r16
.def    allon = r17
.def    ledtemp = r18
.def    bitlow = r20
.def    bithigh= r21

    ldi     ledtemp,0x00
    ldi     allon,0xff
reset:


    ldi     bithigh, 0x07       
    ldi     bitlow, 0x07
    out     OCR1AH,bithigh
    out     OCR1AL,bitlow

    ldi     temp,0b00010000
    out     TIMSK,temp

    ldi     temp,0x0d
    out     TCCR1B,temp

    sei



loop:   
    rjmp    loop


tc0_ocm_isr:    
    eor     ledtemp,allon
    out     DDRB,ledtemp
    reti
```

Answer (score 0):

No, you need to write one program. Your instructor is asking you to understand how interrupts work. I have only ever done this kind of program in C, so you will have to look elsewhere for a tutorial on the topic or wait for another answer.

Your program will set registers that control some clock and then use `SEI` before entering a loop that has one instruction that puts the chip to sleep. You have to choose the correct sleep mode so that the clocks still run and interrupts still occur.

You will also write a subroutine interrupt handler that you never call. Instead, you have cleverly set up the clock to call your handler when a compare interrupt occurs when the clock reaches a certain value.

Since the chip is running so fast, the handler will be called much before 1 second, so your routine will have to do something like incrementing a counter variable until is reaches a certain value. If it reaches the value, reset the counter and toggle the LED. The handler ends with an `RETI` instruction to let the processor know to return the the main loop where it was interrupted.

You will need to study the manual for the processor. It is available from the Atmel website. In particular, choose a clock for your interrupt handler (16 bits will last longer between interrupts), and look at the register descriptions at the end of the chapter. You will want to set a prescaler to slow the clock counter down, and choose an appropriate compare value so that it is easy to get a multiple to reach 1 second.

The pseudo code for the interrupt handler will be something like

```
add a number to the compare register to set up the next interrupt

if counter < limit then increment counter (this is not the clock counter. It is a variable in memory you have declared)
else reset the counter variable to 0 and toggle the LEDs
rti
```